# Regex total limit number of total characters

Tags: c#, regex

I am using regex to assert that my string is a combination of a maximum of 4 numbers separated by commas, the numbers must be between 1 and 4.
Examples of valid strings would be :

```
1,2,3
1,2
1
1,2,3,4
4,1
```

To achieve this i am using `^[1-4](,[1-4])*$`, but i am not able to limit the number of characters on the string. so in my implementation the following string is also valid `1,2,3,4,2,3` which is against what i am trying to achieve.

Comment: Have you tried something like `{0,3}` instead of `*`? Also I think you have one `)` too many in that example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this：

```
^[1-4](,[1-4]){0,3}$
```

Comment: Or better discard the groups and just check whether its matching by using `^[1-4](?:,[1-4]){0,3}$` regex [`here`](https://regex101.com/r/tiQwf8/1)

Answer (score 0):

this should do:

```
^[1-4](,[1-4]{1}){0,3}$
```

Comment: The `{1}`s are completely unnecessary.

Comment: Can you explain what that code does? For people starting to learn regular expressions, this can help a lot

Answer (score 0):

Here is your regex : `^[1-4](,[1-4]){0,3}$`.
You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/Voj6i4/2).